# Ethernet cable plugged in but ubuntu says ethernet network disconnected

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet

I am new to Ubuntu and this has been an issue bugging me for a while. I read many many posts online but found none perfectly solves my problems here. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I don't use WiFi.

(apologize for not being able to paste the codes directly here).

- [**Editted(I configured the IP address manually)**]Here is my output to "ifconfig -a":
  [Screenshot for "ifconfig -a"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qJLM.jpg) (I configured the IP address manually)
- Here is my output to "lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2":
  [Screenshot for lspci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtBFq.png)

**---Edited**

- Here is my output to "/ect/network/interfaces":
  [Screenshot for interfaces](http://ubuntuguide.net/fix-cannot-connect-to-wired-internet-problem-in-ubuntu-or-ubuntu-vmware-guest) (I followed this [website](http://ubuntuguide.net/fix-cannot-connect-to-wired-internet-problem-in-ubuntu-or-ubuntu-vmware-guest) and edited my interfaces file but still no luck. I left it what it is after editing)

Please let me know if any other outputs are needed to help diagnosis. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your interface has received and sent packages, so Ubuntu doesn't say that it is disconnected. You have to configure an IP address, either by DHCP or a fixed address.

Comment: @muclux Thanks for your comment but Ubuntu does say it is disconnected? I am currently using DHCP to configure my IP address.

Comment: Your `ifconfig` shows no address, so you didn't git any from DHCP.

Comment: Are you using a graphical desktop ? If not, take a look in /etc/network/interfaces. Can you post the contents ?

Comment: Your `lspci` output seems to indicate that you are inside a virtual machine. Is the host configured to bridge the network to the VM?

Comment: @hatterman Thanks for you comment. I've edited the post and added the output of /etc/network/interfaces. Any advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: @zwets Hi thanks for the comment. Indeed I'm using VMware 12 workstation to host my Ubuntu system and I chose NAT connection so that my other systems on VMware can access this one.

Comment: I think your lan port should be enps33, you have missed a p off. For example, mine is enps025. Also, if you remove your lan config from that file, the lan will be managed by network manager with a gui on your desktop. (Keep the lo entry in the file only)

Comment: @muclux Hi, I manually configured the IP address but still no luck :(. Any idea?

Comment: @hatterman Hi, please refer to my first screenshot "ifconfig -a." I think I am correct on "ens33" rather than "enps33"? Thanks.

Comment: I think its is the other way round, ifcocfig shows the name you have set. Hmm, not sure. That interface name doesnt look right to me. Either way, how have you configures your vmware network ? Is the vmware DHCP server set up right ? I confess I use virtualbox so cant help much with vmware. Do you run a desktop in your guest, if so then dont use the interfaces file to manage your ens33 interface, try network-manager.